# How can I revert the stubbed mock function once mocking is over in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I have used `test:MockFunction` to mock a function. I need to revert it back to use the original function later-on in the code. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code.

```
import ballerina/test;

@test:Mock {
    functionName: "getDatabaseCredentials"
}
test:MockFunction mockDbCredFn = new();

function mockGetDatabaseCredentials() returns string {
    return "postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/database";
}

@test:Config
function test1() {
    test:when(mockDbCredFn).call("mockGetDatabaseCredentials");
    test:assertEquals(getDatabaseCredentials(), "postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/database");
    // I need to call the original function next time I call getDatabaseCredentials()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `test:when(mockDbCredFn).callOriginal` to use the original function as mentioned in the [ballerina guide](https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/mocking/#stub-to-invoke-another-function-in-place-of-the-real).

With that your code will look like,

```
@test:Config
function test1() {
    test:when(mockDbCredFn).call("mockGetDatabaseCredentials");
    test:assertEquals(getDatabaseCredentials(), "postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/database");
    
    test:when(mockDbCredFn).callOriginal();
    test:assertEquals(getDatabaseCredentials(), "mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database");
}
```